# Remove Splash Screen from Cordova App

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

It is possible to remove the splash screen from a cordova android app and set other .html as a initial page?

I already tried removing from config.xml:

```
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

and setting in config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

and still get the splash.html as default or initial page.

Comment: Are you using cordova or phonegap? There are *some* differences. I believe (based on trial/error during past 24hrs) that the config.xml file gets cached when using the phonegap build service so any changes to your config.xml will not be recognised unless you delete the app and re-add it.

Comment: I'm using cordova @fiprojects

Comment: In your config.xml, is index your main page? I mean this: <content src="index.html" />. If you changed the value to splash.html that could be the problem.

Comment: in config.xml I have <content src="index.html" /> @jcarrera

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need splashscreen plugin, try removing it and building again the app:

```
cordova plugin remove splashscreen
cordova build android
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: when I tried cordova plugin remove splashscreen I get Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.